# How to uninstall Python 2.7 and keep Python 3.4?

Tags: python

I think my title is pretty self-explanatory.

I want to uninstall Python 2.7 and keep Python 3.4 intact.  Is this easy to do?  I found a couple of tutorials about how to uninstall Python, but I don't want to uninstall the entire thing.  Also, I am running Spyder (Python 3.6).  This should work just fine after I get rid of 2.7, right.  The reason I am asking all of this is because I installed pandas_datareader and apparently it went to 2.7, but I really wanted it on 3.4.  Finally, I'm assuming, after I unistall 2.7, and run this 'pip install pandas_datareader' it will go to 3.4, right.

I can't seem to control where the install goes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
pip install <module>
```

you can use the following to install the `module` which will install it to `python-3.x` (as long as `python` points to your `python-3.x` directory in your `PATH`):

```
python -m pip install <module>
```

Or alternatively, you can use `pip3` to install it directly to `python-3.x`.

To use `pip3`, you need to navigate to:

```
C:\path\to\python\Scripts\pip3
```

and then run it as:

```
pip3 install <module>
```

and it will be `installed` to `python-3.x` rather than `python-2.x`.

Comment: I tried that and get a message saying Python is not an internal or external command.

Comment: well then you can either add `Python` to your `PATH` (so you can call it from anywhere) or just run the above commands in the `directory` where you have `Python` installed.

Comment: Thanks.  I did those things.  It still doesn't do what I would expect it to do.  Every six months or so I try to learn Python, but I can't ever get it to do even the most simple things, and then I give up for another 6 months.  I think this should take less than 1 minute to setup, not hours and hours and hours.

I just updated my original post with a couple new pics.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to uninstall a Python just use Windows' Add/Remove programs and run the uninstaller for that specific version.

Later versions of Python include PyLauncher (py.exe) and install it to `C:\Windows` which is always in the path.  Use it to control which Python to run and which pip to run if you have several installed.  If you use this you won't have to add a specific version of Python or its Scripts directory (where pip.exe is) to your path.

Examples:

```
py -3 -m pip install <package>   # Use latest Python 3 installed.
py -2 -m pip install <package>   # Use latest Python 2.
py -3.3                          # Run Python 3.3
py -2.7-32                       # Run 32-Python 2.7 on a 64-bit OS.
py                               # Run default Python (usually latest 3.x)
```

The `PY_PYTHON` environment variable can override the default.

See also: [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html?highlight=python%20launcher#python-launcher-for-windows)